# Threat protection and bot detection policies in Azure API Manager

Tags: azure-api-management

1) Both Apigee and WSO2 have OOTB threat protection policies for threats such as XML Bombs, XML External Entity Attacks, XPath Injection, Javascript Injection etc. Does Azure API manager support that?

2) Apigee supports bot detection. Does Azure APIM support that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. APIM doesn't have that, but another Azure product - App Gateway - does similar things: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-gateway/. I can be setup to work with APIM.
2. APIM doesn't have that either, not sure about anything else in Azure.